# MS SQL Server - use Case Statement to create a single row from 3 records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table that has numeric fields for session and question. Each session has questions 1, 2, and 3. 1= "Effort", 2 = "Satisfaction" and 3 = "Knowledge". There are 5 possible answers 'Extremely Satisfied', 'Very Satisfied', 'Somewhat Satisfied', 'Unsatisfied', 'Extremely Unsatisfied.

The table looks like this:

```
Session  Question  Answer
-------  --------  ------------------
1        1         Unsatisfied
1        2         Very Satisfied
1        3         Somewhat Satisfied
```

I want the report to look like this:

```
Session  Effort          Knowledge       Satisfaction
-------  --------------  --------------  --------------
1        Unsatisfied     Unsatisfied     Very Satisfied
2        Very Satisfied  Very Satisfied  Very Satisfied
```

However, when I use my case statements I get:

```
Session  Question  Effort       Knowledge       Satisfaction
-------  --------  -----------  --------------  ------------
1        1         Unsatisfied  NULL            NULL
1        2         NULL         Very Satisfied  NULL
1        3         NULL         NULL            Unsatisfied
```

The query I'm using is:

```
select 
    distinct session
    ,Question
    ,case
      when Question = '1' 
      then Answer
            end as "Effort"
,case
      when Question = '3' 
      then Answer
            end as "Knowledge"
,case
      when Question ='2' 
      then Answer
            end as "Satisfaction"
from Survey_Table
```

Any ideas on how I can get the data to return as a single row per Session?

Comment: What version of MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 4):

Try this which applies an aggregate to the CASE statement:

```
select session
   ,max(case when Question = '1' then Answer end) as Effort
   ,max(case when Question = '3' then Answer end) as Knowledge
   ,max(case when Question ='2' then Answer end) as Satisfaction
from Survey_Table
Group by session
```

Or you can use the PIVOT function:

```
 Select session,
     [1] as effort,
     [2] as satisfaction,
     [3] as knowledge
 From
 (
       Select session, question, answer
       From survey_table
  ) src
  Pivot
  ( 
      Max(answer)
      For question in ([1], [2], [3])
  ) piv
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note: [bluefeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14076485/57611) already covers this basic method. I just wanted to point out another way to structure the `PIVOT`. You really should have your own table to associate the `Question` column values with titles, but in such a table's absence, I would personally encode this information as a derived table instead of linking up the `[1], [2], [3]` Question values to their corresponding titles with explicit column aliases:

```
SELECT
   P.*
FROM
   (
      SELECT T.SessionID, Q.Title, T.Answer
      FROM
         dbo.SurveyTable T
         INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 1, 'Effort'
            UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Knowledge'
            UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Satisfaction'
         ) Q (Question, Title)
            ON T.Question = Q.Question
   ) S
   PIVOT (Max(Q.Answer) FOR Q.Title IN (Effort, Knowledge, Satisfaction)) P
```

This will work in MS SQL Server 2005 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

You can combine max with partition by to remove the need to group by. e.g.

```
max(case when xxx ='123' then yyy end) OVER(PARTITION BY a,b,c) AS Test1
```